# Filtering DataTable with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

i have two DataTables one with a hughe List of Results and one with a List of Companys from another DataBase.

Well i need to filter the Results on the Companys in the other DataTable.

Something like this:

DataTable Results

0 | FA1 | Resultx
1 | FA2 | Resulty
2 | FA3 | Resultz
3 | FA4 | ResultAA

DataTable Company

FA2
FA4

So i'm looking for a way to filter the first DataTable with the Results of the second DataTable.

Thanks Lim

Comment: You need two join to datatable
see this post in StackOverflow
[Create combined DataTable from two DataTables joined with LINQ. C#][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379747/create-combined-datatable-from-two-datatables-joined-with-linq-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Linq To Dataset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx). These are LINQ extension you can use against datatables.

This [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386969.aspx) shows you how do to a cross table query. It comes down to something like:

```
var query =
    from result in Results.AsEnumerable()
    join company in Companies.AsEnumerable()
    on result .Field<int>("....") equals
        company .Field<int>("....")
select new { .... }
```