# C# merge two tables (preserving column names)

Tags: c#, linq, join, datatable, merge

I am new to C#. I am just looking for a function which is similar to the "merge" function in python, I've struggled a lot but still don't find an easy way.

My objective is to simply merge two tables to one table (keeping the column names), below is example:

```
Table #1: Person
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcZ2d.png)

```
Table #2: Car

car_number  car_color
111         black
122         red

Target output table:
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXNlE.png)

I have tried LINQ

```
var results = from table1 in person.AsEnumerable()
                                  join table2 in car.AsEnumerable() on Convert.ToInt32(table1["car_number"]) equals Convert.ToInt32(table2["car_number"])
                                  select new { table1, table2 };
```

But here the trouble is that the `CopyToDataTable()` function is no longer supported. And it is difficult to save the results to datatable keeping column names.

I also checked the function `"Merge" in C#`, but it seems it requires a column of primary keys which contains only unique values.

Comment: Your images are not available, please reattach

Comment: There is an answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379747/create-combined-datatable-from-two-datatables-joined-with-linq-c-sharp][1]

Comment: A simple join on two tables using linq shall work, in this case

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278978/combining-n-datatables-into-a-single-datatable